# How to round value by specific value after decimal and change all value to zero after round

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding

I use excel and i have question.
I have value look like

```
7,500,300
```

If value after first comma less than 5(it 5 on my case) now round  value into 0.
If value after first comma greater than or equal 5 now value into 5

Example:

```
7,500,300 => 7,500,000
7,520,200 => 7,500,000
7,940,200 => 7,500,000
7,240,300 => 7,000,000
```

I using command look like :

```
=IF((VALUE(MID(7,940,200,FIND(",",7,940,200)+1,1))>=5),ROUND(7,940,200),ROUNDDOWN(7,940,200)
```

But it not working.

Please help me. Thanks you

Comment: How does this work exactly: apart from the 1st example you go from 8 digits to 7 losing a multiple of 10? Also, in your explanation you mention if the digit after the 1st comma <= 5 then.... also if this digit >= 5 then.... One of these has to not be equal to 5 to not be both true. Can you also please rework your own attempt, since that simply is not a valid formula.

Comment: @JvdV I had edit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=INT(A1/1000000)*1000000 + IF(MOD(A1,1000000)>=500000,500000,0)`

Comment: Thanks you but it not working. 
When i enter value : 7,595,000.00 => it into 7,000,000 . I want it change to 7,500,000

Comment: That is strange: for me it works. Maybe this is an international issue? Are your commas decimal or thousand separators - I would assume thousand ...

Comment: Oh it working. When i edit format it work. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to round it down to the previous half-million?

Just divide by half a million, `FLOOR` or `INT` it, then multiply it back up:

```
=FLOOR(A1/500000,1)*500000
'OR
=INT(A1/500000)*500000
```

Process:

```
7,500,300 →{÷500,000}→ 15.0006 →{FLOOR or INT}→ 15 →{*500,000}→ 7,500,000
7,520,200 →{÷500,000}→ 15.0404 →{FLOOR or INT}→ 15 →{*500,000}→ 7,500,000
7,940,200 →{÷500,000}→ 15.8804 →{FLOOR or INT}→ 15 →{*500,000}→ 7,500,000
7,240,300 →{÷500,000}→ 14.4806 →{FLOOR or INT}→ 14 →{*500,000}→ 7,000,000
```

Comment: Why not just `=FLOOR.MATH(A1,500000)`?